# Using reflection to get method name and parameters

Tags: c#, .net, memcached, system.reflection

I am trying to workout a way to programatically create a key for [Memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached), based on the method name and parameters. So if I have a method,

```
string GetName(int param1, int param2);
```

it would return:

```
string key = "GetName(1,2)";
```

I know you can get the MethodBase using reflection, but how do I get the parameters values in the string, not the parameter types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting value of parms using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867482/getting-value-of-parms-using-reflection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is an interceptor. Like the name says, an interceptor intercepts a method invocation and allows you to perform things before and after a method is called. This is quite popular in many caching and logging frameworks.

Answer (score 15):

You can't get method parameter values from reflection. You'd have to use the debugging/profiling API. You can get the parameter names and types, but not the parameters themselves. Sorry...

Comment: At my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729580/how-to-get-the-parameter-names-of-an-objects-constructors-reflection people answer than you cannot get parameter names either -- maybe this is why you got downvoted.

Comment: With Reflection you can get parameter names: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet This is basically a duplicate of your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1867496/4660897), only that answer has some nice links and that question is formatted a little better.

Comment: @TotZam: Well, and that answer was written nearly 11 months later... I'm not quite sure what the purpose of your comment is.

Comment: @JonSkeet I originally was thinking that it might make sense to update this answer with the additional information, or at least have a link pointing to the answer with more information. If the questions are really the same though, then it probably makes sense to just close one of the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I've come up with (however, it may not be particularly efficient):

```
MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
string key = method.Name + "(";
for (int i = 0; i < method.GetParameters().Length; i++) {
  key += method.GetParameters().GetValue(i);
  if (i < method.GetParameters().Length - 1)
    key += ",";
}
key += ")";
```

Comment: While the most important point is that I don't think this does what you think it does, yes it's inefficient - in various ways. Would you like to see a more efficient version which does the same thing, just for educational value?

Comment: (looped string concatenation vs StringBuilder, multiple calls to GetParameters(), etc).

Comment: @JonSkeet - I would really appreciate it if you demonstrated the proper implementation of this method. I would like to use it in conjunction with Diagnostic.Stopwatch to performance monitor some methods depending on parameters passed. Basically looking for "Method A (paramA = 1, paramB = 2) took 00:00:03.023 to execute.

Comment: @Talon: See my answer, and Scott Muc's.

Comment: Inefficient? Yes. Do what i want? Yes... Thanks! I will improve this but its great