# Is there a way to obtain the bytecode for a class at runtime?

Tags: java, runtime, bytecode

In Java, is there a way (at runtime) to obtain the bytecode which defined a particular class?

Put another way, is there a way to obtain the `byte[]` array passed to `ClassLoader.defineClass(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len)` when a particular class was loaded? I see that this method is declared `final`, so creating a custom `ClassLoader` to intercept class definitions seems out of the question.

In the past, I have used the class's `ClassLoader` to obtain the bytecode via the `getResourceAsStream(String)` method, but I would prefer a more canonical solution.

Comment: Why is <code>getResourceAsStream(String)</code> not canonical ?

Comment: @Riduidel: Not all class loaders expose the bytecode as a resource. For example, some custom class loaders generate bytecode *on the fly* and don't bother returning it when `getResourceAsStream` is called.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but why do you need to get the byte codes for a given class? Presumably you don't want to use getResourceAsStream because some classes might be loaded by another classloader?

Comment: @Geoff: I actually want the debugging symbols to help infer method parameter names at runtime as per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729580

Comment: @Geoff: In the past, I used the *class's* class loader (as opposed to the current thread's class loader or the system class loader) to increase the odds of finding the bytecode. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110427020009/http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-1) is a description how to implement an agent

Answer (score 5):

"Java agents" would be the obvious solution.

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard of agents before!