# Get bytecode from loaded class

Tags: java, class, classloader

Suppose in my JVM I have a loaded class `Class<C> myClass`. Is there a *reliable* way to ask the JVM for the <del>bytecode</del> contents of the .class? I.e. something like this:

```
<C> byte[] getClassBytecode(Class<C> myClass) {
    return /* the contents of the .class resource where C was loaded from */;
}
```

(obviously an `InputStream` would be as good as the `byte[]`). I know I can use `myClass.getResource()` (and friends) to fetch the class file, but hammering on the class name to get an URL to feed to getResource feels wrong. Also, I am not sure how this would behave in case `C` was dynamically generated (e.g. using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`).

Any (better) idea?

note: the goal is to be able to push the <del>bytecode</del> classes to a different JVM and use a custom classloader to load them there

Comment: please take a look at: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130903/java-getting-bytecode-of-class-at-runtime-from-within-the-same-jvm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737285/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-bytecode-for-a-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> note: the goal is to be able to load the bytecode using a custom classloader on a different JVM

A classloader [doesn't just load bytecode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html). Therefore, if you *were* able to get the bytecode out of the JVM memory (which is theoretically possible if you write a lot of implementation-specific native code), it would be useless to your remote classloader. You need to give it an actual `.class` file.

And [Class.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) is the best way to accomplish this task. Since it looks in the same package as the invoking class, all you need to do is take the class' simple name, append ".class" and you're done.

It does become a little more difficult if you have inner or nested classes, but that's an implementation detail that you'll have to deal with regardless (if you push the initial class, you'll still need to pull any dependent classes).

Comment: sorry, my bad: with "bytecode" I really meant "the contents of the .class file"

Answer (score 4):

You can use ASM library to get the detail bytecode of a class. A sample code is below.

```
     public class AAA extends ClassLoader{
       public static void main(){
        String resource = caller.replace('.', '/')+".class";
        InputStream is = getResourceAsStream(resource);
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

        ClassVisitor visitor = new BCMerge(Opcodes.ASM5, cw, callee);
        cr.accept(visitor, 0);
    }
  }
  class BCMerge extends ClassVisitor{
         public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        System.out.println(name);
        if (cv != null) {
            return new MyMethodVisit(cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions));
        }
        return null;
    }
   }

public class MyMethodVisit extends MethodVisitor{
    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name,
            String desc, boolean itf) {
            System.out.println("opcode:" + opcode + " owner:" + owner + " name:"+ name + " desc:" + desc);
            return super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf);
    }
}
```