# Printing function definition in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a sequence of functions

```
scala> a.foreach(println)

<function1>
<function1>
<function1>
<function1>
<function1>
```

It sounds impossible but I wonder if scala provides any way to actually print the definition of these functions at the end of this foreach loop?

Comment: Definition in what? Scala source code? How would that work given that it compiles to bytecode? Anyways, this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737285/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-the-bytecode-for-a-class-at-runtime

Comment: Yes, either some bytecode or some clue as to what the function does (perhaps in the form of an anonymous function)

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Good question :) These functions are generated programmatically and I'd like to make sure they are correct.