# Retrieve Groovy Closure/Method parameters list

Tags: grails, groovy

How do we retrieve the list of parameters of a closure/method in groovy dynamically, javascript style through the arguments array

say for example that i want to log a message this way

```
def closure = {name,id ->
 log.debug "Executing method with params name:${} id:${id}"
}
```

OR

```
void method (String name,String id) {
 log.debug "Executing method with params name:${} id:${id}"
}
```

I read once about a way to reference the list of parameters of a closure, but i have no recollection of that and looking at the groovy API for [Closure](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) reveals only *getParametersType()* method. As for the method, there is a way to call a method as a closure and then i can retrieve the method parameters

ken

Answer (score 2):

You won't like it (and I hope it's not my bad to do research and to answer), however:

There is *no* API to access the list of parameters declared in a Groovy `Closure` or in a Java `Method`.

I've also looked at related types, including (for Groovy) `MetaClass`, and sub-types, and types in the `org.codehaus.groovy.reflection` package, and (for Java) types in the `java.lang.reflect` package.

Furthermore, I did an extensive Google search to *trace extraterrestrials*. ;-)

If we need a variable-length list of closure or method arguments, we can use an `Object[]` array, a `List`, or `varargs` as parameters:

```
def closure = { id, Object... args ->
    println id
    args.each { println it }
}
closure.call(1, "foo", "bar")
```

Well, that's the limitations and options!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names can be retrieved if the compiler included debugging symbols, though not through the standard Java Reflection API.

See this post for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2729907/395921

Answer (score -1):

I think you may want to take a look at varargs http://www.javalobby.org/articles/groovy-intro3/