# Can we get closure information when using reflection on Grails?

Tags: grails, reflection, groovy

So we have a task to produce documentation for a REST API we are building. We are using Grails and it's all nicely defined in `UrlMappings` but that doesn't generate a documentation the way we want.

We thought of using reflection to extract the mappings into some format that we can manipulate through code.

There's also a possibility of maybe parsing the `UrlMappings` as a text file and produce some data format that we can manipulate.

For the reflection bit, can we extract info from Closures - such as properties, methods, etc - in Groovy?

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Found this question but not entirely sure yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114190/retrieve-groovy-closure-method-parameters-list

Comment: although I have no idea where to start, you might look into groovy's abstract syntax tree--it gives you the structure of the code as it is compiled--you might be able to get information out of that.  If you load a class into GroovyConsole there is an option to bring up the AST and see if it helps, at least.

Comment: Hi Bill K, I guess that's more or less what I'm after. At least the GroovyConsole gave me a list of ClosureExpressions which show me that is possible to get detailed information about Closures. Thank you for that!

Comment: @TMan Would this plugin be of interest for you? http://grails.org/plugin/grails-runtime-docs

Comment: @TMan Sorry I can't help more, I just know of it's existence, not how to use it although it looks amazingly powerful--so I don't think it's worth leaving as an answer.  If anyone knows of a really good tutorial on how to really use AST trees in groovy please drop a link :)

Comment: @herom, no luck man, that's not what I'm after. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @BillK That's cool man, it does look very powerful indeed. I just wish I had a bit more knowledge of Groovy to play with AST .. but hey, that's cool. Thanks!