# Groovy Closure parameters names

Tags: groovy, parameters, closures, metadata

I have the following closure: 
def check = {x,y,z -> some code}

Is it possible to get the parameters names("x","y","z") inside the closure?
and to use it as part of the closure code

For example to print arg name and then it's value.

Thanks

Comment: Within the closure you know what their names are. But if from outside the closure you want to know what all arguments are being passed to it and their values, then you can't do that.

Comment: I want to use them within the closure. For example: def check = {x,y -> println **arg1Name + x}

Comment: There is no direct way for doing this. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4114190/1799527

Answer (score 0):

You can use of course these parameters in closure.

```
def a = {a, b, c ->
    a + b + c
}
assert 6 == a(1,2,3)
```

Second version

```
def a = {a, b, c ->
    [a:a, b:b, c:c]
}
assert [a:1, b:2, c:3] == a(1,2,3)
```

Comment: of course this is possible.
My problem is to get their **names** and not their values.

Comment: ok, why do you want to use these values?
and for what?
 we can find another way maybe.

Comment: I need to create a map where the key is the arg name and the value is arg value

Comment: i added "second version"  in the above code. please check.