# Groovy, convenient print signatures for methods with arguments

Tags: groovy

I have some Groovy class, for example:

```
class Apple {
   public void methodA(String myParam) {}
   public void methodB(String myParam2, String myParam3) {}
}
```

And I want to print all methods of class Apple in convenient format, for example:

```
Class Apple: 
- methodA <String: myParam>
- methodB <String: myParam2> <String: myParam3>
```

or just:

```
Class Apple: 
- methodA <myParam>
- methodB <myParam2> <myParam3>
```

Is it possible in Groovy?

For now I'm using for-each loop for Apple.metaClass.methods and printing method.name, for example:

```
for (MetaMethod metaMethod in Apple.metaClass.methods) {
    println metaMethod.name
}
```

But I can't find a way to print names of arguments.. 
Also, is it possible to know if there are default values for the arguments?

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No(*).  Parameter names are not stored with the bytecode (I believe they might be if the class is compiled with debugging turned on, but I've not tried it).

(* it **is** possible with [some non-reflection digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729580/how-to-get-the-parameter-names-of-an-objects-constructors-reflection/2729907#2729907), but it relies on a lot of things, and feels like it would be quite a brittle point in your design)

With Java 7 and below, you can just get the types of the arguments.  With Java 8, a new `getParameters` call was added to `java.lang.reflect.Method`, so with Java 8 and Groovy 2.3+ it's possible to do:

```
class Apple {
   public void methodA(String myParam) {}
   public void methodB(String myParam2, String myParam3) {}
}

Apple.class.declaredMethods
           .findAll { !it.synthetic }
           .each { println "$it.name $it.parameters.name" }
```

To print:

```
methodB : [arg0, arg1]
methodA : [arg0]
```

But as you can see, the original parameter names are again lost.

As for default values, the way Groovy handles these is to create multiple methods.  If you declare a method:

```
class Apple {
    public void foo( bar="quux" ) { println bar }
}
```

Then this generates two methods in bytecode:

```
public void foo() { foo( 'quux' ) }
public void foo( bar ) { println bar }
```

If you run the above method inspector for this class containing the method `foo`, you'll see the output is:

```
foo : [arg0]
foo : []
```