# Extracting names of a method arguments using org.objectweb.asm

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to extract method and argument names from JAR file using [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) (org.objectweb.asm) library. I use [`MethodNode.localVariables`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.2/org/objectweb/asm/tree/MethodNode.html#localVariables) property to get those argument names.

I know I have to compile java sources using `javac -parameters` to embed parameter names into the class files, but for some reason `MethodNode.localVariables` is always null. I can tell that parameter names are available because I'm able to extract them with Java reflection. `MethodNode.localVariables` is not null only when I use the option `-g:vars`, which is what I don't want to do.

Is there any reason why ASM can't extract parameter names from classes compiled with the `-parameters` option?

Comment: As the name strongly suggests, `localVariables` is for local variables. Not parameters.

Comment: Have you tried: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.2/org/objectweb/asm/tree/MethodNode.html#parameters

Comment: @rzwitserloot, `localVariables ` contains also argument names, including `this` reference for non static methods.

Comment: @majakthecoder No, they don't.

Comment: @rzwitserloot they do, I tested it. Check out the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729580/how-to-get-the-parameter-names-of-an-objects-constructors-reflection
if you compile java with `javac -g:vars` you will get argument names in `localVariables`.

Comment: @majakthecoder and that's not where `-parameters` goes, nor what the relevant reflection methods look at. It's a bit odd to ask a question but then insist you know precisely how it all works. Did you check boneill's link?

Comment: @boneill, you're right, `parameters` is what I need. I was confused by some old posts where ppl suggested to use `localVariables` for this. Looks like parameters of a method goes to `MethodNode.localVariables` when a class is compiled with `-g:vars`, and to `MethodNode.parameters` when compiled with `-parameters`.

Comment: That's because `-parameters` is much newer than the debug information about local variables. So you might find a lot of recommendations from the time where the `localVariables` was the only option.