# Can I get the attribute name associated with MethodHandle.invoke() in java?

Tags: java

I am using `MethodHandle` of java 7 to set/get attribute value of a POJO class(instead of conventional getters and setters). I am using `MethodHandle.invoke()` for the same.

My application needs to know the attribute name associated with the above invocation.

Is there a way to get the attribute name involved with the `MethodHandle`.

If it is of type Method then it is possible with reflection. But can anyone tell me how to do the same in MethodHandle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using reflection to get method name and parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471693/using-reflection-to-get-method-name-and-parameters)

Comment: @Andremoniy Note that, with Java 8, [it is possible to determine the parameter names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455403/how-to-get-method-parameter-names-in-java-8-using-reflection/21455958#21455958) if specific preconditions are met.

Comment: answer is no at runtime : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection